# Adding One-To-One field to the default Django user model

Tags: django

I'm trying to add one-to-one field to the default Django user model but
for some reason I keep getting error from the database:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: frontend_usermodel.test_suites_id
```

this is models file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models


class TestSuite(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)


class UserModel(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test_suites = models.OneToOneField(TestSuite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserModel.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

What can I do to solve this ?

**UPDATE:**

```
class TestSuite(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: why are you creating an intermediate model `UserModel` if the only thing it does is have one-one connections to `User` and `TestSuite`? Why not just define the `OneToOne` relationship on `TestSuite`?

Comment: @dirkgroten . Because apparently I need to "link" the model to User (Django's default) and then I can add another relationship to it. I thought I could just do this `class UserModel(User):` and just add one more relationship field to it but that wouldn't work

Comment: It really depends what you want to do on the long run. If your `UserModel` is some kind of profile (call it `Profile` then) to which you will add other fields, then this is fine. Except I would set the `OneToOneField` on the `TestSuite` model rather than the profile model. Otherwise, just set the `OneToOneField` on your `TestSuite` model and skip the `UserModel` entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Your `UserModel` requires both fields `user` and `test_suites`, so this line:

```
UserModel.objects.create(user=instance)
```

will fail because `test_suites` is `None` and therefore the NULL constraint is violated. You have to pass also a `TestSuite` instance to create your `UserModel` instance.

Although I don't know the exact business requirements of your application, it would seem more logical to me to set the `OneToOneField` on the `TestSuite`. I can imagine a user without test suite, and I would expect only when you create a test suite, you would assign the user. By doing that, you won't need a `TestSuite` instance when creating a `User`.

Comment: The idea is to for user being able add test suite to his account. If he logs out and logs back in he can see all the test suites he created.

Comment: but you're modelling a OneToOne relationship so a user can only have one test suite.

Comment: You should just forget about `UserModel`, if you don't have plans for extending the `User` model as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).